# Microsoft Graph - Is it possible to access all events in all calendars shared with me using one GET request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I've figured out how I can loop through all the calendars I want to read and do separate GET requests to read the events in them, but is there a way to do this in one GET request? It seems like I need to provide either a user id or calendar id at some point in the url.